# Wordpress -Unable to find the JS code snippet in page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have little experience with Wordpress .

I am trying to edit the JS file of my page . I can find those lines in browser console and I am also aware of the fact that a Wordpress page is rendered from Database.

But there are two JS code snippets in my page and they have an icon as follows :
[image]

Can someone please help in guiding me where are these JS code snippet actually place so that i can edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in visual tab of your editor. You need to go into text tab which will show you the coding of your page, that you can find at top right corner in editor.